Will converting a PSD to WebP using an online make it lose clarity?
I asked for .webp format banner for our website. Our agency sent a PSD file and they told me to convert it to whatever format I want.
If we convert the PSD to WebP using an online conversion tool, will the image lose clarity?
Or do we need to use Photoshop to keep the clarity of the image?

Hi. There's no real way to answer your question regarding the capabilities of some unknown online converter. PSD is a proprietary format (owned by Adobe). Some software can open some PSDs, and some might not be able to do so properly, so nothing is guaranteed.  Why not just try it and see?

so @BillyKerr if there is banner image with width : 2500 and height : 750 , can we make it as width : 750 keeping the height same ? as we need it for mobile banner ? is it possible through psd file ?

Yes it's possbile in Photoshop and would involve resampling the image.  I have no idea what would or would not be possible using an online converter or other software. There are too many unknowns here. Sorry. You'll need to try it and see.

A change in file format should not represent any change in the information of the image in general.
The exceptions are:
1. The compression itself. A compression averages some values of the color of the pixel. It uses a chunk instead of individual pixels. Overall it produces artifacts, but should not produce a change in brightness.
2. Losing the color profile. Changing or losing the color profile could result in a change in the overall look of the image. This could be your case. See what checkboxes you have when exporting. There are several versions of color profile so, it could be the case when a color profile checkbox is on, but the version of it is not recognized.

3. One additional reason could be a change in Color mode or Bit depth. for example a CMYK file or a 16bit per channel. See if this is not the case.
4. Merging of layers. If the original file has layers and the target file format does not allow them. Flatten your image first.

There is a difference between saving and exporting. Saving will in theory preserve the attributes of the original file. If the target format do not allow some feature, you export the file, which implies potential changes in the information of the file. Vector>Raster, Layers, Blending modes, bit depth, color mode... In some rare cases the dynamic range, for example when exporting an HDRI image into a tone-mapped one.
